# Is WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings file required to be uploaded to git?

Tags: xcode, git

I am developing an iOS app and I was committing my works using bitbucket. During committing, I found a file named "WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings". And the has the following contents in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreviewsEnabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What is the use of this file and is it required to be uploaded to my repository?

Answer (score 0):

If this file is located in

`<Project>.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<user>.xcuserdata/`

in particular within a folder `xcuserdata`, then it's user specific.

Anything within a folder named `xcuserdata` is considered by Xcode to be user specific which you usally won't want to be stored in the git repo.

Your `.gitignore` file should contain a line

`xcuserdata/`

which ensures, that no user specifc data will be part of the repo.

Comment: It is located in xcshareddata

Comment: Then, it's probably considered (by Xcode) to be shared, i.e. stored in the repo. But honestly, I am bit unsure here, because what does "PreviewsEnabled" mean anyway?  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464974/what-is-previewsenabled-key-referring-to-in-xcworkspace-xcshareddata-workspaces